# Example of two undecidable languages that cannot be mapping reduced to each other

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, automata, reductions

I want to find two undecidable languages $A$ and $B$ that $A$ cannot mapping (i.e. many-one) reduce to $B$, $B$ cannot reduce to $A$. One of my thought is to let $A$ be the halting problem, let $B$ be some non-Turing-recognizable language, then it is clear that $B$ cannot reduce to $A$, but I don't know which $B$ can I pick to show that $A$ cannot reduce to $B$

Comment: Try the halting problem and its complement.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus but how can we prove that halting problem cannot reduce to its complement?

Comment: That’s a different question.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus But if I remember correctly, there is indeed a Turing reduction from halting problem to its complement...

Comment: Right, my example should work for many-one reductions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus okay.. But it is Turing reduction in context

Comment: Two random languages would probably work.

Comment: You are asking for two incomparable Turing degrees. These keywords should help you search the web for examples.

Comment: You can also use diagonalization: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math502-F15/Turing_Degrees.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no known *natural* example of such a pair, and indeed there are various results in computability theory suggesting that such a pair does not exist. So to whip up an example one has to do some work.

Below, $\Phi_e$ is the $e$th oracle machine according to some standard enumeration *(in older texts this is often written "$\{e\}$," which ... yeah)*.

---

The simplest approach *(indeed, the easiest I know)* is via **mutual diagonalization**: we build inductively a pair of increasing sequences of finite binary strings $$\sigma_0\prec\sigma_1\prec\sigma_2\prec ...\quad\mbox{and}\quad  \tau_0\prec\tau_1\prec\tau_2\prec ...$$ such that for each $i$ there **do not exist** infinite binary sequences $f,g$ extending $\sigma_i,\tau_i$ respectively such that $\Phi_i^f=g$ or $\Phi_i^g=f$.

- Proving that such sequences in fact exist is a good exercise.

Taking $$a=\bigcup\sigma_i,\quad b=\bigcup\tau_i$$ we then have that $a$ and $b$ are Turing-incomparable. *(Thinking about this construction a bit, we can in fact ensure that $a,b$ are Turing-reducible to the halting problem.)*

---

A better result is that there are **computably enumerable** sets which are Turing incomparable (the *Friedberg-Muchnik theorem*). This is much harder to prove, however; it was the first example of a priority argument.

Yuval Filmus commented that a pair of "random" languages should probably work. There are multiple senses in which this is true - in particular, the set of pairs of infinite binary sequences which are Turing incomparable is both **comeager** and **of full measure** in the space of all pairs of infinite binary strings (with the usual topology and measure). The former observation is basically just the mutual diagonalization argument above, slightly tweaked; the latter is a bit harder to prove. *(In general, in computability theory measure is more complicated than category.)*

- In fact, the proofs of the observations in the previous paragraph actually yield stronger results without significant changes: namely, we get that for every noncomputable infinite binary sequence $f$ the set of infinite binary sequences Turing-incomparable with $f$ is both comeager and of full measure in the space of all infinite binary sequences.

Comment: Thank for such a detailed answer. However, this may seem a bit too complicated for me... I am just an undergrad who start to learn Turing Machine recently. This is just a class exercise so I would not expect the answer to be that hard. Maybe I state the question unclear

Comment: The question asks for Two non Turing decidable language A and B such that A cannot be Turing reduces to B, B cannot be Turing reduced to A. We are given hint that we can choose one of the language to be the halting problem

Comment: @Joe Are you sure it is *Turing* reductions that are being looked for? If so, I think your instructor made a mistake (or this is a challenge problem) - it genuinely is this hard.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that our professor said it should be many-one reduction

Comment: @Joe In that case Yuval Filmus' suggestion works - if a c.e. (respectively, co-c.e.) set is m-reducible to a co-c.e. (resp., c.e.) set, then it is computable (this is a good exercise). Since the halting problem is c.e., its complement is co-c.e., and neither is computable, this tells us that the halting problem and its complement are many-one incomparable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber can you define what $\Phi_i^f$ means?

Comment: also, what does it mean for a sequence $f$ to "extend" another sequence $\sigma_i$?

Comment: also, this answer seems to be for the wrong question: the asker is asking for $\leq_m$, while your answer is about $\leq_T$

Comment: @xdavidliu Two things which are $\le_T$-incomparable are a fortiori $\le_m$-incomparable - my answer is a **stronger** result. Also, note that in the comments the OP clarifies that they're interested in Turing reducibility anyways.

Comment: @xdavidliu Re: sequences, it's just the usual notion of extension: $\alpha$ extends $\beta$ if the length of $\beta$ is $<$ the length of $\alpha$ and for every $n<length(\beta)$ we have $\beta(n)=\alpha(n)$. E.g. $1101$ extends $110$ but does not extend either $11010$ or $01$. Note that this makes sense even when $\alpha$ is infinite.

Comment: @xdavidliu Finally, the notation "$\Phi_i^f$" means "the $i$th Turing machine equipped with an oracle for the infinite string $f$." In older texts this is written "$\{i\}^f$," which ... is not ideal.

Comment: but we are talking about _infinite_ binary sequences; do they even have "lengths"?

Comment: @xdavidliu The length of an infinite binary string is $\omega$. (This is where transfinite ordinals come into play: we can talk about arbitrary-ordinal-length sequences.) If you want to avoid talking about the length of an infinite binary string just use a different phrasing: an infinite string $\alpha$ extends a finite string $\beta$ iff for all $n<length(\beta)$ we have $\alpha(n)=\beta(n)$. It's not a big deal.

Comment: but your answer talks about $f$ extending $\sigma_i$, where _both_ of them are infinite. What does it mean for an infinite binary string to extend another infinite binary string?

Comment: @xdavidliu Whoops, sorry, that's a typo - the $\sigma_i$s/$\tau_i$s should be finite. Fixed!

Comment: The point is that those finite strings are approximations to the infinite strings we want to build; this is sometimes called a *finite extension argument*.

Comment: what is $0^\prime$? also, can you add the definition of that and $\Phi$ to the answer? Sipser readers probably won't be familiar with these notations (even if they are somewhat standard elsewhere).

Comment: @xdavidliu ${\bf 0'}$ is the standard notation for the Turing degree of the halting problem; more generally, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump). I've removed it and defined the $\Phi$-notation, but this is really notation you should familiarize yourself with if you're interested in the topic; Soare is a better source than Sipser here.

Comment: what do you mean by "increasing sequence" of binary strings $\sigma_i$? increasing in what, length? lexicography? little-endian integer value?

Comment: @xdavidliu Exactly what I've written in the next line: that $\gamma\prec \rho$, that is, $\gamma$ is (properly) extended by $\rho$. "$\prec$" is the standard notation for (proper) string/sequence extension.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple example is $A_\mathrm{TM}$ (i.e. the language of $\langle M, w \rangle$ where TM $M$ accepts $w$) and its complement $\overline{A_\mathrm{TM}}$.

$A_\mathrm{TM}$ is recognizable but not decidable, while $\overline{A_\mathrm{TM}}$ is not even recognizable (if it *were*, then $A_\mathrm{TM}$ would be decidable!).

Clearly, $A_\mathrm{TM}$ is not mapping reducible (i.e. not many-one reducible) to its complement, since if it were, then its complement would be recognizable.

Comment: Note that Yuval Filmus mentions this in his comment to the OP, and the OP responds by clarifying that they're looking for Turing reducibility. (They then edited the question *from* Turing reducibility *to* many-one, after they'd already accepted my answer ... so that's a bit confusing.)

Comment: I'm guessing the OP had incorrectly assumed when asking the question that the two were the same thing.